# Make the sidebar collapse linear and avoid vertical misalignments

Tags: html, css

I have implemented a sidebar and the collapse function (`for minimizing the sidebar`) works quite okay, but whenever I click on 'collapse' again to `maximize` the sidebar, the elements inside the sidebar are misaligned during few milliseconds and the logo text appears above the body. Please see the images below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How could I make it smoother and avoid the misalignments? It should be something linear without any vertical changes.

I've tried so many things but it was impossible for me to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit(2): [This code](https://www.codinglabweb.com/2021/04/responsive-side-navigation-bar-in-html.html) is from [Coding Lab](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBlr2jG1onljL-gUy9bbhJw), the way he did it is by replacing the class with another class every time you click the hamburger icon, changing it from `bx-menu-alt-right` to `bx-menu` or vice versa.

Since you minimize your sidebar basically to `width: 0` when it reaches screen width of `786px`, you could just make the logo and the whole sidebar content to disappear. Refer to this [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70fwqhon/2/), I've added some css style on your media query to not display the logo when your media query is true.

```css
/* Google Font Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins" , sans-serif;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 78px;
  background: #11101D;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.open{
  width: 250px;
}
.sidebar .logo-details{
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar .logo-details .icon{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
.sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name{
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar .logo-details #btn{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.open .logo-details #btn{
  text-align: right;
}
.sidebar i{
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar .nav-list{
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar li{
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar li .tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}
.sidebar li:hover .tooltip{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.sidebar.open li .tooltip{
  display: none;
}
.sidebar input{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #1d1b31;
}
.sidebar.open input{
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar .bx-search{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}
.sidebar.open .bx-search:hover{
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}
.sidebar .bx-search:hover{
  background: #FFF;
  color: #11101d;
}
.sidebar li a{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #11101D;
}
.sidebar li a:hover{
  background: #FFF;
}
.sidebar li a .links_name{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.sidebar.open li a .links_name{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #11101D;
}
.sidebar li i{
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
.sidebar li.profile{
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 78px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar.open li.profile{
  width: 250px;
}
.sidebar li .profile-details{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.sidebar li img{
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.sidebar li.profile .name,
.sidebar li.profile .job{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar li.profile .job{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.sidebar .profile #log_out{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #1d1b31;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.sidebar.open .profile #log_out{
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
}
.home-section{
  position: relative;
  background: #E4E9F7;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}
.sidebar.open ~ .home-section{
  left: 250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
.home-section .text{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 18px
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar li .tooltip{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created by CodingLab |www.youtube.com/CodingLabYT-->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<title> Responsive Sidebar Menu  | CodingLab </title>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class='bx bxl-c-plus-plus icon'></i>
        <div class="logo_name">CodingLab</div>
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn" ></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
          <i class='bx bx-search' ></i>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
         <span class="tooltip">Search</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
         <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-user' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">User</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">User</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-chat' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Messages</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Messages</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Analytics</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Analytics</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-folder' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">File Manager</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Files</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-cart-alt' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Order</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Order</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-heart' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Saved</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Saved</span>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
         <i class='bx bx-cog' ></i>
         <span class="links_name">Setting</span>
       </a>
       <span class="tooltip">Setting</span>
     </li>
     <li class="profile">
         <div class="profile-details">
           <!--<img src="profile.jpg" alt="profileImg">-->
           <div class="name_job">
             <div class="name">Prem Shahi</div>
             <div class="job">Web designer</div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <i class='bx bx-log-out' id="log_out" ></i>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section class="home-section">
      <div class="text">Dashboard</div>
  </section>
  <script>
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-search");

  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
    menuBtnChange();//calling the function(optional)
  });

  searchBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ // Sidebar open when you click on the search iocn
    sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
    menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
  });

  // following are the code to change sidebar button(optional)
  function menuBtnChange() {
   if(sidebar.classList.contains("open")){
     closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right");//replacing the iocns class
   }else {
     closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right","bx-menu");//replacing the iocns class
   }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  svg, #sidebarLinks{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Edit: If you want to minimize and expand the sidebar using a toggle-button and leave the icons then  you should separate the icons from their title/description and hide ONLY the title/description on clicking the toggle-button. Change sidebar `width` whenever you click using `.style.property`. Anyway [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEfaoAa99XY&t=445s) is a video tutorial about this same feature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work as expected.

Maybe I didn't explain myself well, I am looking for something like this: 

https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-5-sidebar-menu-toggle-button-34132202

The collapse toggle is in a different position but I think you can get the concept easily.

Thank you so much

Comment: Then you should separate the `icons` from their title/description and hide ONLY the title/description on clicking the toggle-button. I'll be going to leave work in a few minutes, so I'll be editing my answer and link to you a video on how to make this work, so if you haven't found a solution by the time I got a free time home, I'll help you with the code.

Comment: That sounds promising, thank you very much and no rush

Comment: @Cheknov I basically copied the code from Coding Lab. You can check it out for your reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it is still not clear to me how to hook it up with my current code, I need some time to process everything.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond a certain width your icons and texts are bound to wrap around or overlap. It's not really a misalignment but default behavior.

What you can do is reduce the font size of your text on minimize/maximize sidebar for a range of width, say from 0px to 150px width, change your text font size to be smaller. You can also use vmin, vmax instead of px or rem for font size. Also, restrict the sidebar minimum width by changing 0 to a specific value in .card class.

Or, you can only display the icons on collapse and hide the text.

Comment: Right now I am hiding the text, but apparently, it's not the best way to go. 
Could you provide a code sample? I want to visualize the content progressively at the same time the 'bar' moves without overlapping/misalignments

Comment: Could you provide a code sample please? I'm curious and sounds promising